# build GPS tacking app with web technology on android device

Tags: android, html, web

I am familiar with web tech (html5) and want to build an app to track location in background in every 5 mins. so, the required features include auto start, GPS location, run in background in every 5 mins.

I want to know if i do it with an pure web tech. if not, which html based framework can do it well, such as RN, WEEX, Angular?

thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research these days and have my answer here. I preferred the solution with Ionicframework with Cordova and its plugins.

if I did a correct search, I can get the answer quickly. This https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation provided a solution for me.

why choose Ionic?
Ionic provided a framework to build an app for devices, desktop, and web. It is not a perfect solution but can help me deliver my app to all platform easily. I am not sure if Ionic is OK to build a high-quality app because it depends on some immature library or tools. But it can reduce lots of work to build a prototype with limited resource. What you need just an HTML5 developer.

I do not choose RN because RN only supports Device. cannot be deployed to desktop and published as web app.